# Mongoid validations: using acceptance with a Proc (or lambda) is not working ? But using inclusion does work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, mongoid, proc

On any given model:

```
class MyTestModel
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :my_field

  validates : my_field, inclusion: { in: proc { |my_instance| [ my_instance.some_stuf ] } }

  def some_stuff
   'some generated value'
  end

end
```

So this works and validates properly, if my_field does not contain `'some generated value'`

But the error validation is not really explicit and I have the feeling that I am using inclusion for no good reason here. What I would like to write for the validation is:

`validates : my_field, acceptance: { accept: proc { |my_instance| my_instance.some_stuf } }`

But this will ***never*** pass validation ? and I haven't found a way to see what the validation is expecting as a *value* to check what is wrong. Any idea why one is working and not the other ? Is that a mongoid bug ?

Comment: I would be guessing that the acceptance validator isn't smart enough to actually evaluate the proc and check my_field against the result... it might well be checking the value of my_field with the actual proc object... which would, of course, fail.

Comment: You must be right. But is surprises me that "acceptance" would be _dumb_ and "inclusion" is _smart_. Why the different behavior? Maybe it's the same with active_recode. Not sure at all.

Comment: Check it's actually evaluating the proc by raising an exception inside it... eg `proc { |my_instance| raise my_instance.some_stuf } }` would be a good thing to check that it's actually getting the right value

Comment: somehow it is actually not raising anything... it just returns `false` for `.valid?` this is so weird... no exception, nothing!

Answer (score 0):

why not write a custom validator method. Then it's clear what you're doing - rather than having multiple layers of obscuring procs.

```
validate :my_field_in_some_stuff

def my_field_in_some_stuff
  errors.add(:my_field, "my field must... but it wasn't") unless ['some generated value'].include?(self.my_field)
end
```

or if the some_stuff method is used elsewhere

```
validate :my_field_in_some_stuff

def my_field_in_some_stuff
  errors.add(:my_field, "my field must... but it wasn't") unless some_stuff.include?(self.my_field)
end

def some_stuff
  'some generated value'
end
```

Comment: Thx for the suggestion, I thought about it and I definitely could. But I don't like writing custom validator unless I really have too. And in this case, I believe a regular "acceptance" validator should be the right way to go, because in the end, I am just willing to accept one value here, and that's what it is for...

Comment: FYI, actually my _some_stuff_ method, is really just a delegated method to the parent document of _MyTestModel_ instance. Because actually in my case  MyTestModel is an embedded model in another one. So in the end the logic is really about accepting only one value in a child object that is supposed to be the same as a value provided in the parent.

Comment: Ok, so if it's a class-method, why not call it instead of passing the proc?  `validates : my_field, acceptance: { accept: OtherClass.class_method }`

Comment: It's not a class method, it's an instance method of the parent object.